# Node serial port write error [Error: Writing to COM port (WriteFileEx): Invalid handle] error occoured while write second time

Tags: node.js, express, serial-port, node-serialport

Iam trying to write in EDC using node serial port when i start and write first time it is success but the second try its return the error and 3rd try success same behaviour continuing

**Error:**

```
[Error: Writing to COM port (WriteFileEx): Invalid handle]
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
at onwriteError (internal/streams/writable.js:389:22)
at onwrite (internal/streams/writable.js:426:7)
```

And i have attached the log which i got from write execption

```
[Error: Writing to COM port (WriteFileEx): Invalid handle]
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
```

Iam closing the port (port.close()) after every transaction and and i initialize the node serial port object at the begining of every transaction

**Code:**

```
const port = new SerialPort(serialPortConfig, { baudRate: parseInt(baudRateConfig) }).setEncoding('hex');  

const parser = new Readline();
port.pipe(parser);

port.write(data, (writeError) => {
  if (writeError) {
    console.log('[inside writeAndDrain write error::', writeError);
  }
 })

port.drain((drainError) => {
  if (drainError) {
    console.log('[inside writeAndDrain drain error::', drainError);
  }
});

port.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('[response]:', data)
  port.unpipe(parser);
  port.destroy((destroyError) => {
      console.log('[destroyError]:', destroyError)
    })
  port.close();
})
```

Can anyone give me the solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you try removing close() from the process?

Comment: Thank you for your replay @kunif i tried but if i remove the close() also same error after the write

Comment: For example, isn't it strange to think that each transaction is open/close? Why not open it when you start the application and close it when you exit the application?

Comment: I have tried the same but the device is denied to access continually

Comment: What are the details of the error notified at that time? Perhaps you are making a mistake. Please add the entire source code and configuration information to the extent that others can reproduce and verify the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)